# Haskell: type versus pattern matching

Tags: haskell

I´m a second-year under-graduate student and have just started learning Haskell. My problem is regarding type-handling versus pattern-matching. I have defined a type Car which contains different parameters and the specification if the car´s gearbox is a stick or automatic, like so:

```
data Car = Stick [Char] Integer | Automatic [Char] Integer
```

This solution has worked brilliantly for pattern-matching cars so far, but now I need a function which takes a car as input and returns the Stick/Automatic information, and don´t want to have to change the Stick/Automatic handling to string-handling. I don´t know what return-type to specify for that function. What would that return-type be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could introduce a new type for the type of tranmission:

```
data TransmissionType = Stick | Automatic
```

and change your definition of car to:

```
data Car = Car TransmissionType [Char] Integer
```

You can then add a function to get the type

```
transmissionType :: Car -> TransmissionType
transmissionType (Car t _ _) = t
```

Since you only have one constructor you could use records instead:

```
data Car = Car {
    transmissionType :: TransmissionType,
    field1 :: [Char],
    field2 :: Integer
}
```

If you don't want to change your definition you could add a function

```
isManual :: Car -> Bool
isManual (Stick _ _) = True
isManual (Automatic _ _) = False
```

Answer (score -6):

In Haskell, the return-type you write in the code (in the declaration) is not for the compiler. It is for you. The compiler figures out what type your function is, then checks whether you got it right.

What I suggest you do, is to make the function you need. ( I haven't really figured out what that should be.) After you have done that, open ghci (the compiler, interactive), load your code. then use :t to have the compiler figure out what type it is. Then you can write it in the declaration if you want to. It is not necessary.

```
$ ghci
prelude> :load yourfile
prelude> :t yourfunction
```

Comment: -1 type inference isn't magical, you still need to have some idea of return type is

Comment: You don't need to write the type down, but if you can't figure it out on your own that just means you don't actually know what your program does.